# Cannot find type 'AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, awss3transfermanager, awss3transferutility

I am new in Swift. Since I update podfile I am facing issue in AWSS3

```
Cannot find type 'AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest' in scope
Cannot find type 'AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest' in scope
```

There is also `import AWSS3` in ViewController.

I am not understanding the problem. Did someone face the same issue?

I also check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659346/awss3transfermanageruploadrequest-in-xcode-7`

But it does not help.

```
    var uploadRequests = Array<AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest?>()
    var uploadFileURLs = Array<URL?>()    
    var downloadRequests = Array<AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest?>()
    
        func download(_ downloadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest) {
            switch (downloadRequest.state) {
            case .notStarted, .paused:
                let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
                transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(block: { (task) -> AWSTask<AnyObject>? in
                    if let error = task.error {
                        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain as String
                            && AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType(rawValue: error.code) == AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.paused {
                            print("Download paused.")
                        } else {
                            print("download failed: [\(error)]")
                        }
                    } else if let exception = task.error {
                        print("download failed: [\(exception)]")
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            print("downloaded file url: \(downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL)")
    //                        if let index = self.indexOfDownloadRequest(self.downloadRequests, downloadRequest: downloadRequest) {
    //                            self.downloadRequests[index] = nil
    //                            self.downloadFileURLs[index] = downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL
    //                            
    //                            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    //                            self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
    //                        }
                        })
                    }
                    return nil
                })
                
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        func downloadAll() {
            for (_, value) in self.downloadRequests.enumerated() {
                if let downloadRequest = value {
                    if downloadRequest.state == .notStarted
                        || downloadRequest.state == .paused {
                        self.download(downloadRequest)
                    }
                }
            }
            
    //        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

func listObjects() {
        let s3 = AWSS3.default()
        
        let listObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
        listObjectsRequest?.bucket = "dice-ios"
        s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest!).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("listObjects failed: [\(error)]")
            }
            if let exception = task.error {
                print("listObjects failed: [\(exception)]")
            }
            if let listObjectsOutput = task.result {
                if let contents = listObjectsOutput.contents {
                    for s3Object in contents {
                        
                        let downloadingFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("download").appendingPathComponent(s3Object.key!)
                        let downloadingFilePath = downloadingFileURL.path
                        
                        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: downloadingFilePath) {
                            self.downloadRequests.append(nil)
                            self.downloadFileURLs.append(downloadingFileURL)
                        } else {
                            let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
                            downloadRequest?.bucket = "dice-ios"
                            downloadRequest?.key = s3Object.key
                            downloadRequest?.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL
                            
                            self.downloadRequests.append(downloadRequest)
                            self.downloadFileURLs.append(nil)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
//                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

My code is like this I am getting issue since I update the podfile.I am facing issue in AWS3 as it is updated. I need to know what to replace.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: @RajaKishan Please check now updated question

Comment: This is old version code now use AWSS3TransferUtility

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios ? Because in the "Storage", they seem to use something else. Which version ar eyou using? Seems outdated.

Comment: Or you want to still use old code use old version pod 2.6.27

Answer (score 1):

I coped with the same problem when I was integrating the pod named AWSS3.

I fixed it by installing the specific version of these pods.
Please check this URL
`https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSS3#changelog`

In my case, I installed the v2.16.0.

I think it is concerning with the Xcode version.

`pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.16.0'`

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your AWSS3 pod version. Check the pod folder to see if the tool you're using is there (In my case, AWSS3TransferManager.h was missing from current version, downgraded to a version that had it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift package manager to add the package, make sure you use the github url https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios-spm.git, not https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-swift.git.